Train a neural network on tabular data - loss on validation data stagnates
I am training a neural network on tabular data. I have a training set and a validation set with 55000 and 20000 samples respectively. I have trained it with 200 epochs. I observe a steady decrease in loss (mean squared error) on the training set and a decrease/stagnation on the validation set. This is not what I expect, because at some point the loss on the validation set should increase (overfit) after all, but I don't see that, it's stationary after 80 epochs. This is confusing me. Does anyone have any thoughts on this? Appreciate your help.
